# Autofac optional/lazy dependencies

Tags: c#, autofac, lazy-initialization

If I put Lazy in constructor of my object, and X is not registered in container I got dependency resolution exception.

Why am I getting this exception? I dislike it, because I cannot choose component at runtime. Example usecase:

```
class Controller
{
   public Controller(Lazy<A> a, Lazy<B> b) { /* (...) */ }

 Lazy<A> a;
 Lazy<B> b;

 public IActionResult Get(){
  if(someConfig)
    return Json(a.Value.Execute());
  else
    return Json(b.Value.Execute());
 }
}
```

To do so I need to register both components A an B. My program fails even if B is never used. I would like to have B be optional, and still managed by autofac.

This is even bigger issue if I have list of components, and want only one to be used. For example:

```
class Controller
{
    Controller(IEnumerable<Component> components) { /* (...) */ }

    IActionResult Get()
    {
        return components.First(n => n.Name == configuredComponent).Execute();

    }

}
```

I am no longer getting exception is something is not registered, however still everything is constructed. Also it would be awkward to use.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you add a reference to a `Lazy<T>` component, Autofac has to know (basically) how to create the internal function that will run *should you want to resolve it*, even if you *don't* resolve it.

Basically, it needs to be able to create this in memory:

```
var lazy = new Lazy<T>(() => scope.Resolve<T>());
```

Autofac requires all of the things you want to resolve to be registered. It doesn't let you register things on the fly - it must be explicit. So the thing you're trying to do won't work (as you saw).

Instead, use a single interface and two different implementations of that interface. Change the registration based on your configuration value.

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
if(someConfig)
{
  builder.RegisterType<A>().As<IService>();
}
else
{
  builder.RegisterType<B>().As<IService>();
}
```

Then in your controller, inject the interface rather than the concrete class.

```
public MyController(Lazy<IService> service)
```

There are also other options you could do, like use [metadata](http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/metadata.html) for components or [keyed services](http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/keyed-services.html). For example, you could add some metadata based on your configuration and resolve using that.

```
builder.RegisterType<A>()
       .As<IService>()
       .WithMetadata("Name", "a");
builder.RegisterType<B>()
       .As<IService>()
       .WithMetadata("Name", "b");
```

In the controller, you'd get a dictionary of them:

```
public MyController(IEnumerable<Meta<IService>> services)
{
  var service = services.First(s => s.Metadata["Name"].Equals(someConfig);
}
```

That's a very short example, but [the docs show a lot more](http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/metadata.html).

In any case, the interface is really going to be your key to success. If you're just using concrete classes, they'll have to be registered whether you use them or not.